# Random access to element in TF (2.0) Dataset

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

Suppose I have TensorFlow  Dataset, and I am using TF 2.0.
I can iterate on each element with `for` loop:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
ds = tfds.load('coco', data_dir='D:\\DataSet\\COCO')
test_data = ds["test"]
for rec in test_data:
     print(rec['image'])
```

Is it possible to access the Nth element directly?
something like `rec = test_data[N]`?

Comment: May be you can try test_data.enumerate().filter(lambda x, y: x==N-1)

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible at this moment. If you have control on how the dataset is loaded, the closest I have come up with is to create a generator that supports random access, and create a dataset from this generator using `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible now ([4.9.0](https://github.com/tensorflow/datasets/releases/tag/v4.9.0) or later) using the new data_source API, see https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/tfless_tfds

```
ds = tfds.data_source('fashion_mnist')
ds['train'][0]
```